Woher weiß ich, auf welches Verb sich ein Adverb beim AcI bezieht?

Ich höre die Frau deutlich singen.

Ist hier grammatisch klar, auf welches Verb sich deutlich beziehen muss?
Bedeutungstechnisch könnte deutlich sowohl zu hören als auch singen passen.
Kann man bei einem AcI (Accusativus cum Infinitivo) grammatisch bestimmen, welchem Verb das Adverb zugeordnet wird?

Man kann in gewissen Grenzen eine Bindung durch die Nähe des Adverbs zum Verb ausdrücken (ich höre deutlich die Frau singen vs. ich höre die Frau deutlich singen). Vollkommen deterministisch ist das aber nicht in jedem Fall, und es mag sich für manchen auch holprig anhören.

Die Antwort ist (leider?), daß es keineswegs klar ist, worauf sich das Attribut bezieht. Es gibt beide Deutungsmöglichkeiten: man hört deutlich und sie singt oder man hört und sie singt deutlich.
Man kann diese Doppeldeutigkeit auflösen, indem man einen Relativsatz aus dem ACI bildet oder das Attribut näher an das Verb rückt:

Ich höre deutlich, daß die Frau singt.
Ich höre die Frau, die deutlich singt.
Ich höre deutlich die Frau singen.

Wenn man das zweite Verb wegläßt, dann sind die Möglichkeiten:

Ich höre deutlich die Frau.
Ich höre die Frau deutlich.

beide korrekt, was die Ursache des Problems (oder, je nach Ansicht, auch der Vorzug) ist. Bei der ersten Form ist die Eindeutigkeit der Zuordnung noch gegeben und bleibt beim Hinzufügen des zweiten Verbs erhalten, bei der zweiten jedoch nicht.
Obiter dictum: ich halte diesen Umstand eher für einen Vorzug der Sprache. Ein Verständigungsmittel, das zu mehr als dem Mitteilen von Börsenkursen taugt, sollte solche Doppeldeutigkeiten erlauben und (um Karl Kraus zu paraphrasieren) den Leser dazu bringen, einen Satz so lange zu durchdenken, wie der Autor gebraucht hat, ihn zu schreiben.

Ich stelle dein Beispiel mal als Nebensatz bereit:

Du weißt, dass ich die Frau deutlich singen höre.

Und damit beantwortet sich auch deine Frage. Das Adverb deutlich qualifiziert die Verbgruppe singen hören als ganzes. Im Hauptsatz ist das nicht anders, nur dass dir die V2-Regel dort das konjugierte Verb wegschießt.

Das stimmt nicht! Tatsächlich kann der genannte Satz bedeuten, daß man hört, daß die Frau deutlich singt oder, daß man deutlich hört, wie die Frau singt. Der Satz, den Sie draus gemacht haben, ist genauso doppeldeutig. Es sollte aber Einigkeit  darüber bestehen, daß das Attribut nur eines - das Hören oder das Singen - qualifizieren kann, auch wenn das, was es nun qualifiziert, daraus nicht hervorgeht.
